# In Outlook 2010, where is a reply to an Appointment saved?

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010

In Microsoft Outlook 2010, I have this setting turned on: "when replying to a message that is not in the Inbox, save the reply in the same folder".

That is exactly what I want.

However, I recently replied to an Appointment in my calendar... and now I can't find where my email was saved to!

Where is a reply to an Appointment saved?

Comment: I know this sounds simple, but did it save it in the Sent Items folder?

Comment: Duh... yup, you are right. That's where it goes. Thanks. If you add your comment as an Answer, I'll accept it for you :)

Comment: My confusion arose because I was looking for a key word that was not in my email, so I wasn't finding it.

Comment: It's always nice when it's something simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this sounds simple, but look in the Sent Items folder.